# How to append a Linked List to back of another?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I've implemented my own Linked List type of data structure but I'm running into a problem when I want to append one linked list to another without iterating over anything.

Here is an example with the output I wanted

```
public class MyList{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyList list1 = new MyList(3);
        MyList list2 = new MyList(4);

        System.out.println(list1);  //0 1 2
        System.out.println(list2);  //0 1 2 3

        list1.add(list2);

        System.out.println(list1);  //0 1 2 0 1 2 3
        System.out.println(list2);  //0 1 2 3
    }

    private class Node{
        public int data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public Node head;
    public Node tail;

    public MyList(int length){
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            add(new Node(i));
        }
    }

    public void add(Node node) {
        if (head == null) {
            //insert first node
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {
            //add node to end
            tail.next = node;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
    }

    //Problem!
    public void add(MyList list) {

    } 

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        for(Node iter = head; iter != null; iter = iter.next){
            result += iter.data + " ";
        }
        return result;
    }   
}
```

When list2 is added to list1, I want list1 to be extended without breaking the original list2. I can't see how to do this without iterating over anything though. It is trivial to iterate over list2 in the add method and add each node to the end individually but this doesn't feel right to do with linked lists.

Can anyone give me some advice on how I could do this efficiently

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

- Set the `tail.next` of first `list` to the `head` of the 2nd `list`.
- and then re-assign the `tail` of 2<sup>nd</sup> `list` to the `tail` of 1<sup>st</sup> `list`

So, this is how your method should look like:

```
public void add(MyList list) {
    this.tail.next = list.head;
    this.tail = list.tail;
}
```

And you should better name this method as `extend`. That shows the intent of the method more clearly.

Comment: This reminded me of an exercise on my C/C++ class some years ago. +1 for nostalgia (and for being a good answer :P).

Comment: Well I'm stumped. I made the above code as an example for a problem I have within a bigger project and in that project I tried this exact method and it didn't work but lo and behold, it works here! Guess I need to go looking through my code a little more

Comment: @Gamb. Same happened to me. At those times, LinkedList were like the scariest topic, that took the hell out of me.

Comment: @MarkDunne. Well, sure. :)

Comment: I know you've answered the question given but I found where my original problem was coming from. In my bigger project, as well as add one list to another, I wanted the expanding list to become a circular linked list. I thought this was as simple as adding

`tail.next = head;`

to the end of the method but this seems to break everything. Now both lists grow longer with the back of one being at the front of the other. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @MarkDunne. That's because your `tail.next` is referring to the same node as `list.tail.next`. They both are two references to same node. An alternative would be to create a copy of nodes from the `list`, and add it to your invoking list.

Comment: So the solution must be to iterate over all the nodes in `list` in this situation?

Comment: @MarkDunne. Wait. I think you would have to iterate through the 2nd list to make the copy of each node. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `head` of input list to the `tail` of this list. just write it as code:

```
public void add(MyList list) 
{
    this.tail.next = list.head;
    this.tail = list.tail;
}
```